# execute external javascript function in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

In my react application the API sends some javascript function as a string

i.e. `export const test=()=>{alert('Function from external source');} export const v=()=>void` is sent. now I get it in my react application and as the state changes the component re-renders.

now, how can I call the `test`function in my component at`componentDidUpdate` or any other lifecycle hooks?

- I am using Mobx and an observable variable get loaded by that string and as component re-renders that I can get it via props, so this is why `componentDidUpdate` was my first candidate

Comment: `API sends some javascript function as a string` one of the worst pattern ever.

Comment: @samb102 thanks for your sympathy, now any solution?

Comment: Since you cannot `eval` `export` declarations, there is no way to evaluate the string as is as JavaScript. If you can convert this to something else that you can evaluate with `eval` or `new Function`, you could do that, but it's certainly not an ideal approach.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for hints, I was thinking of making a script HTML tag and set the sting as its innerHTML (assume if the string function is in ES5 style) and append it to document. in that case do you have any solution  how to read that script in component

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi yes, drop this pattern.

Comment: @samb102 sure Thanks, I will tell your idea to the project manager